# Google Chrome inactivity redirect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, kiosk

I have chrome opening in kiosk mode - I added the `--kiosk` flag to the chrome shortcut which works as expected.

The kiosk allows browsing of our **intranet** and the **internet**. I realise I can use javascript to redirect pages on our intranet, but what about the internet? We don't want people fpr example browsing to YouTube and then walking away.

We would like to have the browser re-direct to *www.MyDomain.com* after x minutes of inactivity.

I have tried Kiosk [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kiosk/afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban?hl=en) which does exactly what we require but the swipe left/right gestures don't seem to work for page navigation (already contacted the developer via github).

Any suggestions?

Comment: is this 2 questions? I can answer the first, but probably can't help with someone elses Chrome app/extension

Comment: It seems this question (by the same user) was already answered: http://superuser.com/questions/992448/google-chrome-inactivity-redirect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find an answer to this question on [another site](https://superuser.com/questions/992448/google-chrome-inactivity-redirect).

Ended up using a chrome extension called [Idle Reset](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/idle-reset/nnaoeblcffjlledmikadmhhfhjpolcjd?hl=en).

Hopefully it helps somebody else.